# How to make org-mode support to open org-mode link in properties drawer?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Here is the Org-mode buffer example which has a properties drawer.

```
** Kelvin Hu
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BLOG:     http://kelvinh.github.io/
  :END:
```

Comment: Your example works correctly out-of-the-box with zero user-configuration -- start with **Emacs -Q**; block/copy/paste the above example to a `*scratch*` buffer; type `M-x org-mode`; type `M-x show-all` so we can see what we are doing;  place the cursor on the link and type `C-c C-o` and watch the magic.  In my case, the default internet browser Firefox opens the webpage.  A mouse left-click on the link also works correctly.  [Tested with Emacs 24.5.1.]

Comment: @lawlist I tested with `emacs -q`. It did work. I will bisect my init files to find out which configuration changed this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bisect my init files. I found the reason.

Because this option setting which enable latex preview at startup.

```lisp
 (setq org-startup-with-latex-preview t)
```